# Add unique random identifier to new Firebase child with Zapier/Google Sheets

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, zapier

I am connecting a Google Sheets file to Zapier to automatically create a new child in my `cards` Firebase node when a new spreadsheet row is created. The problem is that I can't find a way to generate an unique identifier with Zapier and/or Google Sheets. What's the best way to generate an unique ID for every child created?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I could add a new column in the Google Sheets to generate a new UID based off the time stamp that row was created but adding a different time stamp every time seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a third alternative as a python script (using only one step)

```
import uuid

return {
'unique_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Zapier support. They said this can be done in two ways:

1. Using https://zapier.com/help/formatter/ there is a Spreadsheet-style Formula option you can use. I know it supports the rand() function and you could take 2 Formatter outputs of rand and then compute them with a 3rd Formatter math step to give you a pretty random value.
2. If you never wanted the possibility of a collision, you could use a https://zapier.com/help/how-get-started-code-zapier/ step and generate a hash, and then use that output as the ID.

Edit: I've simply used the Row ID which is the most convenient method.